# Creating a list or tuple out of one word-per-line in vim

Tags: vim

I come across the following pattern quite frequently, where I have to copy-paste a bunch of items (usually in excel) into something like a SQL query and often the simplest way to do this is copy-paste the data into vim and then run a macro/command on it to format it. Here is an example of input data:

[image]

This involves three steps for me:

- Delete empty lines: `:g!/\S/d`
- Add quotes around it and a `,` separator: `:% s/\v(\S+)/"\1",`
- Put it onto one line and add a wrapping `[...]` or `(...)`: `ggVG` (select all), `J` (condense-all), `0i(CTRL-o$)`

Is there a way I can put all this into a function or macro, or what's the best way that I could take the above input and enter some keyboard shortcut, such as <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> and it formats everything in the above way?

While it might seem overkill, this is something that I can do pretty easily and quickly (without really thinking) in an editor like TextMate where I can use a multi-cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what's the problem? Put this stuff into your vimrc and you're done.

```
function s:do_stuff() abort
    %join
    s/\S\+/"&",/g
    s/^/(
    s/$/)
endfunction

nnoremap <silent><leader>s :call <SID>do_stuff()<CR>
```

Comment: thanks, yes one of the things is I didn't know how to create a function in vim so your question helps point to that direction, thank you. A couple questions: (1) What is `<SID>` ?; (2) What is `s:do_stuff()`, why not just `do_stuff()`, finally, (3) what is `%join`, is this the same as `%J` ?

Comment: @David542 (1) and (2) `s:` means "script-local" function or variable. It won't be accessible from outside (including mappings) unless you specify script ID (functions only), which is done by `<SID>`. BTW. `do_stuff()` would be illegal, as global functions must start with a capital letter. (3) `%J` isn't a legal command. `:join` is documented under `:h :join`

Comment: @David542 vimscript is comprised of ex commands. Join is the ex-command for joining lines. Ex commands tend to work linewise and take ranges specifying where they operate. % is the shortcut range for the whole file.

Comment: @Matt one more question: why the `"&"` instead of `"\1"` ?

Comment: @David542 Ampersand refers to the whole match (Vi, Perl). It's shorter, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

My initial reflex is to start with

```
echo '['.join(map(filter(getline(1, '$'), '!empty(v:val)'), 'string(v:val)'),', ').']'
```

Which can be turned into

```
%d
call append(line('.')-1, '['.join(map(filter(getreg('"', 1, 1), '!empty(v:val)'), '"\"".v:val."\""'),', ').']')
```

And thus into the command

```
command! -range=% ToTuple 
\ <line1>,<line2>d
\|call append(<line1>-1, '['.join(map(filter(getreg('"', 1, 1), '!empty(v:val)'), '"\"".v:val."\""'),', ').']')
```

Note that

```
echo string(filter(getreg('"', 1, 1), '!empty(v:val)')
```

Would be much simpler, but then single-quotes would be used instead of double-quotes -- it may make a big difference with some languages.

Answer (score 0):

I figured another option:

```
:%s/\v(\w+)\n+/"\1",/g | norm $x | exec "norm! I(\<Esc>A)"
```

As a command line option:

```
vim -c ':%s/\v(\w+)\n+/"\1",/g | norm $x | s/.*/(&)/g' -c wq target.txt

-c ........... vim command line (interactive shell)
\v ........... very magic (simple regex system)
\w+ .......... one or more words per line
\n+ .......... one or more line breaks 
() ........... regex group
\1 ........... repeat the first regex group
normal $x .... deletes the last character of the remaining single line
```

Once I am using only the words `\w+` inside the regex group, the line breaks are ignored in the substitution. In the last substitution we dont need more `%` because at this point we have a single line.