# Surround selection into array

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, pycharm, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I am aware about surrounding selection in quotes or braces

[PhpStorm wrap/surround selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435802/phpstorm-wrap-surround-selection)

I need similar but surround selection into array
Assume I have text separated with newline or text separated with space

a

b

c

d

e

a b c d e

I need after selection get [a,b,c,d,e]

Please advice any IDE or method how to achieve this

Comment: The following question is the same as yours in vim context only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62069376/creating-a-list-or-tuple-out-of-one-word-per-line-in-vim/62071578#62071578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A no-brainer solution

Make sure the following option is enabled:

[image]

For text separated with spaces:

- Select the 'array-to-be', hit `Ctrl+R` and `R` again (to enter 'In selection' mode)
- Type a space in the first field, `,` in the second
- Click 'Replace all', hit `Esc`
- With the text still selected, press `[`: the closing bracket will be added automatically

For multi-line text:

- Select the 'array-to-be', hit `Ctrl+R`, enable 'Regex'
- Type `\n +` in the first field, `,` in the second
- Click 'Replace all', hit `Esc`
- With the text still selected, press `[`: the closing bracket will be added automatically

---

The sequence of actions can be wrapped into a [macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) and assigned a single shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Vim + [Surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround). Enter visual mode, select what you need and press `S]`.

Answer (score 0):

The first group could be created by:

```
:%s/\v(\w)(\n)*/\1,/g | exec "norm! I[\<Esc>A]"
```

It takes care of:

```
a

b
...

\v ........... very magic regex
() ........... regex group
(\w) ......... letters
(\n)* ........ zero or more line breaks
\1 ........... repeat content of the first regex group
```